# How to use joblib parallelization with in-class methods that don't return anything

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I am currently trying to implement a `parallel for` loop using `joblib` in python `3.8.3`.

In the *for* loop I want to apply a class method to an instance of one class while applying a method in another.
This is a MWE that I did to try and see if my idea works, but it does not. Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
    def add5(self):
        self.val += 5

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = [A() for _ in range(10)]
    def apply(self):
        """ this is where I'm trying to use joblib:
        for a in self.obj:
            a.add5()"""

        def f(x):
            x.add5()
        Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(f)(x) for x in self.obj)
    def prnt(self):
        print([a.val for a in self.obj])

b = B()
b.prnt()  # returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b.apply()
b.prnt()  # returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] but
          # I expect [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Some more context to my problem: I am using sci-kit learn to implement a boosting algorithm where I generate weak learners before applying the algorithm. The fitting and predicting is done in a for-loop and can take some time, so I want to add parallelization to try and speed up the progress. Basically, `class A` is a classifier and `class B` is my algorithm, where I want to fit all classifiers that I generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ([source](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html)) one can read that:

> The default backend of joblib will run each function call in isolated
> Python processes, **therefore they cannot mutate a common Python object**
> defined in the main program.
>
> However if the parallel function really needs to rely on the shared
> memory semantics of threads, it should be made explicit with
> require='sharedmem', for instance:

So you have two options: 1) you add `require='sharedmem'` to your `Parallel` For:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=-1, require='sharedmem')(delayed(f)(x) for x in self.obj)
```

However, [source](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) points out that:

> Keep in mind that relying a on the shared-memory semantics is probably
> **suboptimal from a performance point of view** as concurrent access to a
> shared Python object will suffer from lock contention.

In the 2) option, you will have to change two things in your code.

First change the `f` function from:

```
 def f(x):
      x.add5()
```

to return the object back.

```
def f(x):
    x.add5()
    return x
```

and in the `Parallel loop`, change from:

```
  Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(f)(x) for x in self.obj)
```

into:

```
 self.obj = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(f)(x) for x in self.obj)
```

So that you can assign the `self.obj` to the list return by the parallel loop.

Final code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def add5(self):
        self.val += 5


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = [A() for _ in range(10)]

    def apply(self):
        """ this is where I'm trying to use joblib:
        for a in self.obj:
            a.add5()"""

        def f(x):
            x.add5()
            return x

        self.obj = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(f)(x) for x in self.obj)

    def prnt(self):
        print([a.val for a in self.obj])


b = B()
b.prnt()  # returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b.apply()
b.prnt()  # returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] but
          # I expect [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, marked as answered. The second option is the one I implemented and it works like a charm!